# Cauchy-Riemann equations with partial derivative being continuous

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to understand a proof in complex analysis. 
And there is a step that I am not able to see why this ''re writing'' can be done.

define $f(z) = f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$

two small examples (which I understand) with $c = a+ib$

$f(c) = f(a+ib) = u(a,b) + iv(a,b)$

Likewise we have

$f(c+h) = f(a+ib + h) = f((a+h) + ib) = u(a+h,b) + iv(a+h,b) $

But I am having a problem with rewriting this expression:

$z = x+iy, h = p+iq$ The way I am trying to do it is

$f(z+h) = f((x+iy) + (p+iq))$

$= f((x+p) + i(q+y))$

$ = u((x+p),(q+y)) + iv((x+p), (q+y)) (*)$

and that would be my final result but the book says that I need to add

$i(v(a,b+q) - v(a,b))$ to $(*)$

But I am not quite sure where that is coming from

Comment: What even are $a,b$? Neither of those appear in the definitions of $z$, nor $h$. Perhaps you are missing some context? What you got for $f(z + h)$ is correct on my account.

Comment: ahh sorry I forgot that I should compute $f(z+h) - f(c)$ with $c = a+bi$. and I would say $ - f(c) = - u(a,b) - iv(a,b)$ maybe I made a mistake here ?

Comment: Your evaluation of $-f(c)$ is also correct. I would suggest looking more closely at the text and what you are being asked to compute, since it appears to me, at least, that there is not any error in what you've written. What, may I ask, is the peripheral context? What are you computing and why? This could lend a clue to what is causing the discrepancy between what you are getting and what you expect to get.

Comment: Okay let me try to explain more detailed. let $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ for $z = x+iy \in G$ assume $u,v$ have continuous first order partial derivatives in $G$ and that they satisfy cauchy riemann equations at z then $f'(z)$ exists take $h = p + iq$.. Then can I ask you how will you compute $f(z+h) - f(z)$?

Comment: I hope my answer to your question sheds some light on the matter for you. I suspect that the author(s) of your book are adding and subtracting some terms that you are missing. All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z) = u(z) + iv(z)$, $z = x + iy$ and $h = p + iq$. Then
\begin{align*}
f(z+h)-f(z) &= u(z+h) + iv(z+h) - u(z) - iv(z) \\
&= \big(u(z+h)-u(z)\big) + i\big(v(z+h)-v(z)\big) \\
&= \underbrace{\big(u(x + p,y+q)-u(x,y)\big)}_{I} + i\underbrace{\big(v(x+p,y+q)-v(x,y)\big)}_{II}.
\end{align*}

Now, to make use of the fact that $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, your book is likely adding and subtracting some terms from what I am calling $I$ and $II$.

For instance, in $I$:
\begin{align}
I &= u(x + p,y+q)-u(x,y) \\
&= u(x + p,y+q) \color{red}{-u(x+p,y) + u(x+p,y)}-u(x,y) \\
&= \big(\color{blue}{u(x + p,y+q) -u(x+p,y)}\big) + \big(\color{blue}{u(x+p,y) - u(x,y)}\big).
\end{align}
Note that the red highlighted terms together add up to $0$, no matter what $x,p,y$ are. The blue terms in the last line above are reminiscent of the terms we would consider when evaluating the partial derivatives
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}, \quad\text{respectively.}
$$
This kind of trick is useful to keep in mind, and it is what I suspect the author(s) of your book are using when they are computing
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for making it so clear, it makes sense now. adding / multiplying by the identity seems very common in intro complex analysis proofs